# JSON encode not returning values to requested page

Tags: javascript, php, json

- Hi, I'm trying to return SQL results to function with below function and SQL query. If I save the results from
  SQL as JSON ouput the function woks fine by redirecting the url to
  .json file. Is it possible to return the SQL results directly to JSON
  function as input with out saving into json file first? I'm using jeasyui.com pivot feature.

---

### PHP Page 1: (Pivot.php)

```
function load1(){
    $('#pg').pivotgrid({
        url:'process_pivot.php',
        method:'get',
        pivot:{
            rows:['Name'],
            columns:['Account','Department'],
            values:[
                {field:'D_Amount',op:'sum'},
                {field:'A_Amount',op:'sum'},
                {field:'Bill_Amount',op:'sum'},
                {field:'Travel_Amount',op:'sum'}
                 ]
        },
        valuePrecision:0,
        valueStyler:function(value,row,index){
            if (/Discount$/.test(this.field) && value>100 && value<500){
                return 'background:#D8FFD8'
            }
        }
    })
}
```

### PHP Page 2:(process_pivot.php)

```
    $rs = mysql_query("select * from manager_view");

        $items = array();
        while($row = mysql_fetch_object($rs)){
            array_push($items, $row);
        }

        //echo json_encode($items);
        return json_encode($items);// return the JSON reuslts to JSON function above
```

Comment: Well first things first, you gotta stop using `mysql` and make the switch to either `mysqli` or `pdo`.

Comment: Go back to useing `echo json_encode($items);` but then you must look at the pivotgrid to add a method to receive and process that data